# OneToMany always is fetched even i use LazyLoad

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have one simple issue and i'm not sure why this does not work, i would like someone to explain me what and why i always get Roles fetched when queering Users.

Basically i created User class and i added LazyLoaded list of Roles, but when i execute query i always get Roles, and that is something that i do not want to do. Can someone explain me why that is happening ?

Basically what i want to achieve is to get Roles when i want, my understanding was, when i in query use LEFT JOIN FETCH with LazyLoad JUST THEN all roles SHOULD be fetched...

Bellow i added all classes and query that is fetching list of roles, even i did not use LEFT JOIN FETCH in query..

I have simple User class that looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
data class User (
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        var id: Long?,

        var sponsorId: Long,

        var firstName: String,

        var lastName: String,

        var photo: String,

        @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
        var username: String,

        @JsonIgnore
        var password: String,

        @JsonIgnore
        var enabled: Boolean
) {
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        var roles: Set<UserRole> = emptySet()
}
```

Also i have second simple class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_role")
data class UserRole (
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        var id: Long?,

        @JsonIgnore
        var userId: Long?,

        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        var role: Role
)
```

And in my repository i have this Query, as you can see i did not JOIN FETCHED roles, but anyway i get list of users together with list of roles....

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository : JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.sponsorId = :sponsorId")
    fun findAllBySponsorId(@Param("sponsorId") sponsorId: Long): Set<User>

}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's getting fetched? Even with lazy loading if you call user.getRoles(), you will still get them.

Comment: Hmm i do not call explicitly user.getRoles() anywhere, the only thing that i call is that query (findAllBySponsorId)

Comment: Maybe you're serializing to JSON for example, then the marshalling library calls all the getters on its own.

Comment: Is there a way to check that? I call this query on end pont where I am returning list of users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jackson is probably the culprit here, as it was for me.

You need to make Jackson aware that you're using Hibernate.

Add this to your pom, so it can handle the lazy loading properly:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And create a Bean of it, add it for example to your application class:

```
@Bean
public Module hibernate5Module() {
    return new Hibernate5Module();
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's most likely the case. But a partially off-topic and maybe just a personal preference: don't do this. Create a separate class to use in outer communications (a DTO). If that seems like a burden, you can use stuff like Lombok and MapStruct. Unless it's a POC/home project that you're just using to educate yourself, it's not a big price to pay for a good and extensible project architecture.

Comment: Your comment sounds interesting, can you provide simple code example please?

Answer (score 3):

Lazy initialization works but because of `spring.jpa.open-in-view=true (spring default)` your collection is fetched when serializing an object to `JSON`.

Long story short: You have hibernate session bounded with current thread even in the view layer. More [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-open-session-in-view-anti-pattern/)

I would suggest setting `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` which makes things more explicit and has way better performance.

When you only read data I would suggest using projections [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections). Term CQRS would be also helpful for you.